# How to configurate text for ILogger.BeginScope?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SomePostFromBody ( [FromForm] SomeClass obj )
{
    using (_logger.BeginScope("TEST"))
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, "Some critical error");
        DoSmtClass doSmtClass = new DoSmtClass (  );
        doSmtClass.DoSmt ( _logger );
    }

        return "SomePostFromBody" + Guid.NewGuid ( );
    }
}
```

BeginScope all times add something like this into my logs `ConnectionId:0HLGF22CJ57E2 => RequestId:0HLGF22CJ57E2:00000001 RequestPath:/api/first => WebApplication.Controllers.FirstController.SomePostFromBody (WebApplication) => TEST`. How can i change this text?

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Also, read https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/ it may help

Comment: I want to know how to change default information. Which system put to logs. I don't want to see `ConnectionId:0HLGF22CJ57E2 => RequestId:0HLGF22CJ57E2:00000001 RequestPath:/api/first` in every log